# Display values in my report that are not in the database

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

The user needs to enter the Month and Year from comboboxes in my VB form before it launches a Crystal Report. Can I insert that Month and Year into the combobox report form to the crystal report? They are not exist in the database, and I don't want to change the database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You want **Parameters**.

Params are information that the user (or launch program) inputs at runtime. I'd recommend making two string parameters: `Month` and `Year`.

After you've added them in the *Field Explorer -> Parameter Fields* you can either drag them directly onto the page, or reference them in formulas like this:

```
{@Month}
```

Finally, you'll need to follow appropriate steps to make sure your VB form actually sends those values when it launches the report. This will depend on what method you use to launch the report, but Google is your friend on this.

Comment: Thank you, but how to make string parameters? i am a newb here

Comment: @AgilGA You mean inside the report? Go to the "Field Explorer" on the right, right click "Parameter Fields" and select "New..."